# How to conditionally format a cell (in Google Sheets) if its content is present in a separate range of cells?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, gs-conditional-formatting

I have a list of numeric codes in a range on a tab of a Google sheet. These values are non-consecutive, unsorted.

On a separate tab, I would like to conditional format a cell if its content matches any of the individual cells in the aforementioned range.

The best I can do in the "Format cells if..." dropdown is selecting "Text is exactly" and typing a single numeric code. Currently, I have a rule for each of the numeric codes. I would like to replace this collection of single rules with one rule.

Answer (score 0):

```
=FILTER(B1, COUNTIF(INDIRECT("A$1:A"), B1))
```

here is an example of the opposite, so to adapt it for your purpose you need to drop **`NOT()`** and use **`INDIRECT()`** if you want to reference another sheet/tab (and you either use "text contains" or "text is exactly"):

#### green color:

- apply to range **A1:A** custom fx: `=FILTER(A1, NOT(COUNTIF(B1:E, A1)))`

#### red color:

- apply to range **B1:B** custom fx: `=FILTER(B1, NOT(COUNTIF(A$1:A, B1)))`
- apply to range **C1:C** custom fx: `=FILTER(C1, NOT(COUNTIF(A$1:A, C1)))`
- apply to range **D1:D** custom fx: `=FILTER(D1, NOT(COUNTIF(A$1:A, D1)))`
- etc.

[image: 0]